# NSDecimalNumber unit test struggle

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, nsdecimalnumber

I am trying to write unit test for my method doing some operations on NSDecimalNumber. For simplicity I prepared this simple unit test snippet:

```
- (void) testTmp {
    NSDecimalNumber* val = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];
    XCTAssertEqual([val stringValue], @"0");
}
```

Unfortunately it fails and I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong? How do I test if NSDecimalNumber's value equals to other value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XCTAssertEqual()` compares the object references. You should use `XCTAssertEqualObjects()`.

```
- (void) testTmp {
  NSDecimalNumber* val = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];
  XCTAssertEqualObjects([val stringValue], @"0");
}
```

BTW: You should not compare the string representation of the number, but the number itself …:

```
- (void) testTmp {
  NSDecimalNumber* val = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];
  XCTAssertEqualObjects(val, [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"]);
}
```

… or (did not check it, whether `NSNumber` and `NSDecimalNumber` can be equal, but it should be that way) …

```
- (void) testTmp {
  NSDecimalNumber* val = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];
  XCTAssertEqualObjects(val, @0);
}
```

However, instances of `NSDecimalNumber` are floating point values. Comparing them for equity is voodoo.